# Viewport of a scene region in Java Fx

Tags: javafx-2

i have a JavaFx scene with a Region element as ist parent element. Lets say I want this region to have a defined size of 20.000x20.000 Pixels, but Only a window of the size 1024x768.

How can I make my scene display the region area from x-pixel 5.000 and y-pixel 3.000, just similar to a Viewport of the ImageView class? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your Region in a [ScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html).